# Issue with overflow or text in div using css

Tags: css

I have a block of code which is as follows:

```
<?php
if(strpos($page_info[0]['page_title'], 'Service')!==false)
{?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front_assets/images/service.png" width="450px" height="400px"/>
        <br/>
        <div style="width:480px; height: auto; border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; overflow: visible; display: inline-block;">
        <?php
        foreach($service as $srv)
        {?>
        <div style="float:left;width:100px;">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url().$srv['service_image'];?>" width="100px"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:300px">
            <strong><?php echo $srv['service_title'];?></strong>
            <br/>
            <strong><?php echo $srv['service_content'];?></strong>
        </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <?php
        }?>
        </div>

        <?php
}
```

The line `<strong><?php echo $srv['service_content'];?></strong>`
displays a text thats coming from database, which is been added using a ckeditor.

Now let me show you an image:

[image]

See the text is getting out of the div. Now if I set the div's `overflow: hidden`  then the text next to `contact us.` gets hidden.

[image]

I just don't want that, I want the line to get broken after `contact us.`

And the next line gets displayed from `"We are just a phone call away."`

I know this can be fixed by a simple attribute, but I just don't know that.

Comment: Provide a JSfiddle of the code in issue.

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Comment: Go to jsfiddle.net and add the code that is having this issue. Or provide a link where this issue exists.

Comment: http://ghureasi.com/pages/view_page/4-Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fix the `.column p` style which sets the width for the parent `p` to 460px. Change it to `100%`.

You have a style in `style.css` file which sets width for all `p` in `.column1` (file http://ghureasi.com/assets/front_assets/css/style.css):

```
.column1 p{
display:block;
width:460px;
padding:20px 0 25px 3px
}
```

because of `width:460%` you allow this content to grow (and use more space then parent element).

Change it to

```
.column1 p{
display:block;
width:100%;
padding:20px 0 25px 3px
}
```

Comment: didnt get u, please write in detail

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and your issue will be resolved.

```
.column1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 94%;
}
```

**OR**

add width `auto` to `.column1 p` class.

For instance,

```
.column1 p{width:auto;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line

`<strong><?php echo $srv['service_content'];?></strong>`

to

```
<span style="width:250px;">
   <strong><?php echo $srv['service_content'];?></strong>
</span>
```